# Bitwise operations on Armadillo vectors

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, armadillo

I need to do bitwise operations between two vectors. I dont want to use loops. 
I am using Armadillo. Could anyone help me with this?

Edit:

By vector I mean a vector template provided by Armadillo library. Something like this:

urowvec newvec1 = zeros < urowvec >(5);

urowvec newvec2 = ones < urowvec >(5);

urowvec newvec3 = newvec1 | newvec2;

But this gives me error with armadillo.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly? At the lowest level, *every* computation is bitwise.

Comment: I dont mean at the lowest level. I am talking about logical bitwise operations like AND, OR etc. being performed on two vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement this:

```
inline urowvec operator|(const urowvec& lhs, urowvec& rhs){
  // ToDo - operate on an element by element basis, and return
  // a urowvec. Decide on something reasonable if the vectors
  // differ in size.
}
```

and make sure this is included in every compilation unit requiring the operator, then `urowvec newvec3 = newvec1 | newvec2;` *will* be valid.

You can do the same thing for the other bitwise operators.

Any reasonable compiler will *elide* the value copy.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to expedite the bitwise operation by using SIMD commands? As in, if I can operate on the entire vector(or part of it) at once instead of doing element wise operation.

Answer (score 0):

to do bitwise operations use the bitwise operators

```
 |   bitwise or
 &   bitwise and
 ^   bitwise xor
 ~   bitwise not
<<  bitwise shift left
>>  bitwise shift right
```

if you gave a more specific question you might get a more specific answer. By vector do you mean a std::vector, is it a vector of ints? or do you mean an array of bits?

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: I cannot use bitwise operations directly with armadillo vectors

Comment: Same here. boolen operators don't work armadillo types.Try this,
 ucube a = zeros<ucube>(3,3,3); a(1,1,1) ^= 1;